# Online Scrabble-like game with play-ahead feature?

Tags: scrabble

I just played my turn in Words with Friends, and notice I can make a
killer word on my next turn, unless my opponent plays too close to
that area and blocks my making that word.

Are there any online Scrabble-like games that let you say: "on my next
turn, play this word, unless, of course, my opponent makes it
impossible to do so".

I realize there's the possibility that my opponent's play will give me
an even better word, but I'm OK with sacrificing that chance in return 
for a faster and more unique mode of play.

EDIT (to answer comment): my opponent and I are on different 
schedules, so the push notifications would come in the middle of my or 
his night.

Several hours may pass between turns, and a play-ahead option could 
speed up the game by a factor of 2 or more. The speedup would come 
because of the time that passes between turns, not because it takes so 
long to play a word.

Also, when I play a word, Words with Friends already gives me my next 
set of tiles (it refills my tile tray to have 7 tiles), so that's not 
an issue.

Comment: Why aren't push notifications sufficient? They inform you when it is your turn, so you can use a scrap of paper (or notebook software) to write down your word and probably nearest crossword, then when you receive the push notification, post your move. You will also receive your new tiles at that time and can start constructing your next new word. A **future play** feature would still need to inform you of your upcoming tiles and need board state for you to get much of a speed increase. Not sure if this is a problem worth solving (is the interface so bad that entering a move takes a long time?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you play on any Play-by-email site, such as http://www.gamerz.net/pbmserv/scramble.html, then you could tell your email client to automatically respond to their move with your preplanned move. If your new move is invalid, it would just get bounced.

Comment: Hmm, I just realized I didn't add the word 'free'. Would ideally like to find a free solution, though this one is interesting. On http://thepixiepit.co.uk/scrabble/faqs.html the question "Q  I just took my turn, and the score was credited to my opponent, help?" suggests autoreplies are a bad idea?

Comment: Sorry. That site is a horrible example. I'm editing my post with a much better pbem game service.